# What is the purpose of && in React's useState?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and I often see the usage of React's useState like the following line:

`setComment && setComment('Comment');`

Why would you do that with the same useState function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript)

Comment: if `setComment` is a state function then `setComment && setComment(x)` is pointless unless you have somehow unset the function to be undefined/null etc as it should always be a function and therefore checking it's existence is not needed

Comment: This is more of a JavaScript question rather than a React question. Basically what this does is it ensures that setComment is defined before trying to call it.

Comment: Yes, but the OP specifically mentions react state function

Comment: @0stone0 It helps a bit but not in React's context and it doesn't answer the question why you would do such a thing with the same state function. Nevertheless, thanks!

Comment: @DimitarVeljanovski I get the point thanks!

Comment: @andymccullough Your answer perfectly answers my question, thanks a lot!